# Add span text to input text value on click

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, checkbox

I am looking for a way to add text from my span tag into the input value field when you click on a checkbox.

I do not want to use jQuery for this, only JavaScript.

I have done it so it adds the text into the input field but when you actually click on the input it doesn't recognise that my text is there. Does anyone know how I go about this so it recognises I have added text to the input field? Any help would be appreciated.

Code here:

```
const inputContainer = document.querySelector('.input-container');
const spanText = document.querySelector('.span-t');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
const check = document.getElementById('check');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');


/* Add Input Field */
const applyInput = function(){    
    const inputDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const inputContent  = `<div class="input-container">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="input" type="text" name="input-code"  value=""></input>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn" disabled="">
                                    <span>Submit</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>`;

    inputDiv.id = "input-container";
    inputDiv.innerHTML = inputContent; 
};
applyInput();


/* Add Span Text */
const span = document.createElement('div');
if(document.getElementById('p-text') !== null) document.getElementById('p-text').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('p-text'));
span.id = "p-text";
span.innerHTML += '<p class="p-text">P Text<span class="span-t">Span Text</span></p>';
inputContainer.after(span);

/* Add Checkbox */
const addingCheckbox = () => {
    if(document.getElementById('checkbox') !== null) document.getElementById('checkbox').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('checkbox'));

    const addCheckboxHtml = document.createElement('div');
    addCheckboxHtml.id = 'checkbox';
    addCheckboxHtml.className = 'checkboxEl';
    addCheckboxHtml.innerHTML = `<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><span></span></label>`;

    if(document.getElementById('checkbox') === null) {
        spanText.after(addCheckboxHtml);
    }

};
addingCheckbox();

/* Add if Checked */
checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.input').value = spanText.innerHTML;
});

check.onchange = function() {
    btn.disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### SIMPLIFIED CHECK

You can see that this behavior is totally possible - the little snippet below shows a simplified case.

```js
const span = document.querySelector("#from")
const input = document.querySelector("#to")
const cb = document.querySelector("#cb")
const btReset = document.querySelector("#reset")
const btLog = document.querySelector("#log")

cb.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  input.value = span.innerHTML
})

btReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cb.checked = false
  input.value = ''
})

btLog.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("input value:", input.value)
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="from">This is the text.</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="to" /><input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button id="reset">RESET</button><button id="log">LOG INPUT VALUE</button>
</div>
```

#### CODE UPDATE

Now the snippet you gave works without an error.

```js
/* Add Input Field */
const applyInput = function() {
  const inputDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const inputContent = `
<div class="input-container">
  <div>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="input-code" value="" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" disabled="">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</div>
`;

  inputDiv.id = "input-container";
  inputDiv.innerHTML = inputContent;

  // you need to add the created element to the DOM,
  // e.g. append it to the body
  document.body.append(inputDiv)
};
applyInput();

// only elements that are created can be queried, so
// these variables must be initialized AFTER the element(s)
// they are supposed to get exist in the document (DOM)
const inputContainer = document.querySelector('.input-container');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');



/* Add Span Text */
// the creation of the span has to be also encapsulated in
// a function - this way it's easier to handle
const addingSpan = () => {
  const span = document.createElement('div');
  if (document.getElementById('p-text') !== null) document.getElementById('p-text').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('p-text'));
  span.id = "p-text";
  span.innerHTML += '<p class="p-text">P Text<span class="span-t">Span Text</span></p>';
  inputContainer.after(span);
}
addingSpan()
// element after it is actually created
const spanText = document.querySelector('.span-t');

/* Add Checkbox */
const addingCheckbox = () => {
  if (document.getElementById('checkbox') !== null) document.getElementById('checkbox').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('checkbox'));

  const addCheckboxHtml = document.createElement('div');
  addCheckboxHtml.id = 'checkbox';
  addCheckboxHtml.className = 'checkboxEl';
  addCheckboxHtml.innerHTML = `<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><span></span></label>`;

  if (document.getElementById('checkbox') === null) {
    spanText.after(addCheckboxHtml);
  }

};
addingCheckbox();
// element after it is actually created
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
const check = document.getElementById('check');

/* Add if Checked */
checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.input').value = spanText.innerHTML;
});

check.onchange = function() {
  btn.disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

#### UPGRADED CODE

I think the following snippet does what your original code does, but the structure is cleaner, simpler.

```js
const getInputHtml = () => `
<div class="input-container">
  <div>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="input-code"  value=""></input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" disabled="">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</div>
`;

const getSpanHtml = () => `<p class="p-text">P Text<span class="span-t">Span Text</span></p>`;

const getCheckboxHtml = () => `<label class="checkbox-label"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check" /></label>`;

// only execute function, if selector cannot be found in DOM
const ifNotExistsInDomFn = (selector) => (fn) => {
  if (!document.querySelector(selector)) {
    return fn()
  }
}

const appendHtmlStrTo = (el) => (str) => {
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str)
};
const appendHtmlStrToBody = appendHtmlStrTo(document.body);

// IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression
(function() {
  // creating UI
  const inputHtml = getInputHtml()
  appendHtmlStrToBody(inputHtml)
  const spanHtml = getSpanHtml()
  ifNotExistsInDomFn(".p-text")(() => appendHtmlStrToBody(spanHtml))
  const checkboxHtml = getCheckboxHtml()
  ifNotExistsInDomFn(".checkbox")(() => appendHtmlStrToBody(checkboxHtml))

  // setting event handlers
  const cb = document.querySelector(".checkbox")
  cb.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".input").value = document.querySelector(".span-t").innerHTML
  })
  cb.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.querySelector(".btn").disabled = !cb.checked
  })
})();
```